Problems with Geometry Node Set up - collection instances rotate randomly in Blender Render Buffer VS Viewport Render
I have a fully finished tracked VFX shot (please see attached play blast video) and it has instances that rotate and scale up according to the position of two empties.
The geometry nodes look perfect in viewport and in play blast video, but then renders differently with random rotation in render buffer. Pls help.
LINK TO VIEWPORT ANIMATION PLAYBLAST VIDEO: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17sH2wG1Af_v1cDFe3Ge1DvH0qVfD-6yr/view?usp=sharing
GEOMETRY NODES SET UP:

Viewport render of frame 280 (where the scaling and rotation ends):

Viewport Render Vs Render Buffer


"normally" this happens if you have different settings of viewport and render. e.g. in subdiv modifier or whereever this is possible. Since you posted just some pics and i cannot see any problem here, i would recommend providing a blend file (it can be a simplified one, just so that the problem still occurs)

Improbable,, but is the 250-scale Noise  in your second illustration being sampled differently by the Preview, and the Render?
